# global.yaml puppet/hiera with environment management

Tags: global, puppet, environment, hiera

I'm actually running puppet 3.7.2 and hiera 1.3.4 on my Debian Jessie.

My puppet config is:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
#prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
#postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
server = puppetmaster01.prd.lord-y.net
certname = master.localdomain
environment = prod
condir = /etc/puppet
report = false
show_diff = true
trace = true
runinterval=60
usecacheonfailure = false
ignorecache = true
environmentpath=$confdir/environments

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
certname = master.localdomain
#modulepath=$confdir/environments/$environment/modules:$confdir/modules

[agent]
report        = true
show_diff     = true
```

My hiera config:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: "/etc/puppet/environments/%{::environment}/hieradata"
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::fqdn}"
  - global
:logger: console
```

and my puppet environment:

/etc/puppet/environments/{prod,uat,dev}
 ==> environment.conf  hieradata  manifests  modules

In my environment.conf:

```
manifest = /etc/puppet/environments/{prod,uat,dev}/manifests/site.pp
modulepath = /etc/puppet/environments/{prod,uat,dev}/modules
```

In /etc/puppet/environments/{prod,uat,dev}/hieradata, I have my hosts definitions and the global.yaml for each environment.

My problem is that when the master performs Hiera lookups during catalog building, it seems not to obtain data from `global.yaml` in the cases where it should do so.

For example, if I execute this command on my Puppet master machine, it correctly falls back to `global.yaml` to provide the right result ...

```
hiera varnish::dev::settings::site::backend_name ::environment=prod
```

... but when the same key is looked up in the course of serving a catalog request, no value is found.

Comment: You've confused me with your statement that "when it's executed on the client, the right config is not taken".  I wouldn't expect the `hiera` command you presented or anything like it to be executed on the client at all.  In a master/agent setup, it is the master that performs all catalog building, including retrieving data from Hiera where appropriate.

Comment: Yes you're right that's the master who's compiling the catalog and actually, if there is no variable like "varnish::dev::settings::site::backend_name" in the hiera client configuration, the "arnish::dev::settings::site::backend_name" variable must be taken in the global.yaml. It's not the case and I cannot figure out why :S.

Answer (score 0):

If Hiera lookups via the command-line tool produce different results from equivalent lookups performed by the master in the course of catalog building then the only likely explanations lie in the realms of identity and environment.  Inasmuch as Hiera has no documented reliance on environment variables, the most likely conclusion is that your `global.yaml` files are not readable by the puppet master process, which runs with a non-privileged UID and GID that are probably different from those you use in your interactive shell.  Check the permissions on those files, and / or run the command under the master's credentials.

Comment: I figured out what's going on. It was by bad. I wrongly difined hiera variable in the global.yaml file. With the right value, puppet classes are working perfectly.